# Automatically expanding/contracting SVG to the size of its contents

Tags: svg, path, size, containers, overflow

SVG tags have a default size that will stay that size unless explicitly told otherwise and anything that steps outside of this (overflow) is hidden by default.

Is there a built-in way to just make the SVG expand and contract to the size of its contents?

If not, what's a convenient way to get the sum size of all the elements? I'm thinking `getBoundingClientRect`.

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: I was asking what the best way is. Is that manually resizing it with `getBoundingClientRect`?

Comment: Call `getBBox()` on the SVG element, and set the `width` and `height` (and/or the `viewBox`) from those values.

Comment: That technically did it, it's now the same size as the collective size of the contents. However, because I'm using `<path>` elements that may or may not start at the top left corner (`M 0,0`) the box contents are offset. Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll accept it.